# Морфология

Tags: морфология

какой частью речи будет слово "так" в предложении "Так вы её знали?"

Answer (score 4):

В этом предложении ТАК - частица. 
Посмотрите [здесь](http://albooking.net/book_168_glava_12_G.html)

Answer (score 1):

Скорее всего, местоименное значение ТАК употреблено в значении присоединительного союза со значением "в таком случае, следовательно, значит". Сходные выражения: Так едем? Так ты согласен?

ДОПОЛНЕНИЕ

1. В Грамматике-80, а также в различных других источниках, говорится о том, что характерной особенностью многих частиц является то, что  своим функциям они часто сближаются с союзами, вводными словами, местоимениями. Иногда эти связи настолько тесны, что их противопоставление оказывается неправомерным, и слово должно квалифицироваться как «частица-союз», «частица-наречие», «частица-местоимение» и т. д.
2. В нашем случае мы как раз имеем такое тесное единство, которое я определила бы как сочетание УКАЗАТЕЛЬНОЙ ЧАСТИЦЫ И ВВОДНОГО СЛОВА со значением «следовательно, значит». Это следует из сравнения: Так, значит, вы её знали?→ Так вы её знали? Здесь ТАК = ТАК,ЗНАЧИТ – по форме это необособленная частица, а по значению это «указание + вывод».
3. В любом случае этот пример имеет совсем не однозначное решение и поэтому заслуживает ОБСУЖДЕНИЯ – ведь у нас ФОРУМ, а не указатель ссылок. Ссылки хороши, когда вы изложили свое мнение и хотите дополнить  его указанием на полезный по данной теме материал. Люди, которые обращаются на форум, в идеале ждут от нас краткого и точного ответа на вопрос «как правильно и почему», причем в общедоступной для понимания форме. В нашем случае предлагаемая статья – это частное мнение  автора по этой теме, а  отнюдь не единственно верное понимание вопроса.  К тому же она рассчитана на специальную аудиторию.

Comment: А еще можно посмотреть в словаре у Ожегова - там около 13 значений  слова ТАК - среди них союзы, частицы, вводные слова. Я просто выбрала самый подходящий вариант. А еще можно не смотреть, а просто сравнить синтаксическую роль частицы и союза.  Слово ТАК используется в качестве связи с предыдущим содержанием текста, подводит его итог - что-то вроде "так получается, что вы ее знали?". Думаю, что частица вряд ли справится с такой ролью.

Comment: Слова ТАК и ИТАК могут составлять интересную пару, например: Так вы ее знали? - Да, знал. - Итак, вы ее знали. Поэтому слово ТАК по смыслу близко к вводному слову, но не обособляется и выполняет роль союза.

Comment: Большинство форумчан считает ТАК частицей, и мне хочется понять их выбор, так как никаких обоснований они не приводят. Вот я сравниваю два предложения: (1)Так получается, что вы ее знали? (2) Так вы ее знали? В первом предложении ТАК, действительно, является усилительной частицей - ее можно убрать их предложения. Из второго предложения убрать ТАК нельзя, слово имеет значение вывода, можно заменить: Значит, вы ее знали? Неужели  значение вывода может выразить частица?

Comment: Отличие союза от частицы в том, что союз связывает предложения. Контекста вопроса не хватает, чтобы это наглядно увидеть. Возможно, поэтому коллеги не видят функцию союза у слова "так". Екатерина дала хорошую ссылку на исследование о слове "так". В нем есть не только глава о частице "так", но и о слове "так" в роли союза. Вот там примеры приводятся более корректно.